# Работа с Excel

Tags: html, excel

Как в сделать так, чтобы на HTML-странице отображалось содержимое Excel файла? Обязательно, чтобы это было не через сохранение Excel файла в формате HTML "ФАЙЛ > Сохранить как > HTML формат" <<< НЕ ТАК. Т.е. чтобы Excel файл отображался в HTML в нормальном формате.

Если так сделать нельзя, то тогда другой вопрос: есть ли какая-нибудь программа наподобие Excel, в которой так же была таблица и функция "Условное форматирование > Создать правило... > Ячейки, которые содержат..." (это для того, чтобы, к примеру, если я в ячейке написал цифру 4, и она автоматом стала зелёной).

Также мне нужно, чтобы этот файл можно было редактировать на самой странице HTML и сохранять его.

Если можно, то напишите, пожалуйста, HTML код, как это делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читайте файл Excel с помощью PHP (к примеру) и выводите его содержимое через соответствующие теги - `<table>,<tr>,<td>` + к этому оформляйте содержимое через CSS.

А теперь вопрос - оно вам зачем? Судя по предыдущим вопросам у вас, вероятно, не хватит на это знаний. И зачем вам иметь возможность изменять содержимое Excel файла? На мой взгляд, вы не тем путем идете.

Comment: Мне как бы нужно иметь файл, в котором будут некоторые данные. Автоматическое изменение цвета текста нужно для того, чтобы определять, что важно, что нет (у меня будет красный и зелёный). Мне нужно, чтобы этот Excel файл отображался по центру страницы, и мне ещё нужно так, чтобы его можно было изменять. Но я не совсем понял, как это читать файл через PHP?

Comment: хранить данные лучше в БД, если же у вас с этим туго - можно и в файле - но уж точно не Exel. Тогда уж смотрите в строну CSV формата. Но хранить изменяемые данный в файле - это последнее ...

Comment: БД - Вы имеете ввиду Microsoft Office Access BD ? Ну в принципе, если там есть таблица, то вполне подойдёт. А как тогда отобразить файл формата ACCBD в HTML?

Comment: И ещё, забыл сказать, что необходимо иметь возможность изменять его через HTML страницу...

Comment: БД - это база данных (помимо Access, существует MySQL, SQLite, MSSQL, ORACL, Transbase...). Скажите честно, что вы умеете делать на php? Иначе вы  сейчас весь форум закидаете нелепыми вопросами, избежать которых можно, прочитав хотя бы Книжку для Чайников.

Comment: Из PHP я ничего практически не знаю. Если что, я все эти коды из интернета беру. Про PHP у меня вопросов нет. Я стараюсь не использовать PHP на своём сайте.

Comment: В основном у меня HTML и JavaScript.

Comment: в данной задаче без использования серверного языка (php, perl и т д) не обойтись.

Comment: Ну почему? Можно ограничиться использованием только IE и посмотреть на его ActiveX компонены. Вот здесь что-то пишут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555479/export-to-excel-jsp-page

Но в целом автор не совсем правильно понимает суть использования и работы браузера.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно создать ActiveX компонент, содержащий таблицу Excel, к примеру, на Delphi, вставить в страницу.